# Custom Name for Heroku Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, host

So i have deployed my Heroku applications. I've decide to create a custom domain name for it, so I followed the steps on [Heroku official website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

The problem is, i've set up my custom domains and CNAME's alias. But when i type this into my command prompt `"host www.mydomainname.com"` it gives me this

```
"Get-Host : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'www.mydomainname.com'.
At line:1 char:1
+ host www.mydomainname.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Host],ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHostCommand
```

Does this have to wait for the propagation or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you add your domain with  `heroku domains:add www.example.com` command. `host www.mydomainname.com` command is for the domain verification .

Comment: Yes I have done this three times, www.example.com, example.com *.example.com

Comment: You could do this in the Heroku app interface online - [heroku.com](http://i.imgur.com/FKorKZE.png)

Comment: Just read this `You can confirm that your DNS is configured correctly by using the 'host' command, assuming your DNS changes have propagated:` will see what happens tomrrow